# Angle between chord and tangent

Tags: geometry

I am not getting this theorem:

> ***Angle between chord AB and tangent at A is the same as subtended by segment AB at any point on the circumference.***

How to prove this theorem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the fact that if $O$ is the center of circle, and $C$ is foot of the perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$, then the angle subtended at any point on the circumference is half $\angle{AOB}$ which is $\angle{AOC}$ and try showing that the angle between chord $AB$ and tangent at $A$ is the same.

[image]

Note, you do have to be careful here, there are two different angles subtended by points on the circumference, corresponding to the two different arcs which $AB$ forms. In fact those two angles add up to $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: Hey! Can you please put a figure am not getting that abstruse statement :(

Comment: @Deb: Added a figure. Hope that helps.

Comment: It is a shame that one cannot upvote an answer again after it has been edited. :)

Comment: @J.M: Careful...That only removes the previous vote :-)

Answer (score 6):

As a diagram of the other common method of proof of the Alternate Segment Theorem has not yet been posted, here it is.

[image]

AB is the diameter and so $ \angle BCA $ is a right angle. Hence $y = \pi/2 - \angle BAC = x,$
and we just note that the angle subtended by $AC$ is constant in this segment.

Answer (score 2):

It is well known that the angle subtended by segment $AB$ at any point on the circumference is constant on either of the arcs $AB$. Since the sum of those angles is $\pi$, it suffices to prove this for the point $C$ that is opposite to point $A$. Then it is well known that the angle $ABC$ is a right angle and also the segment $CA$ meets the tangent at $A$ in a right angle. Therefore $CAB = \frac{\pi}{2} - BCA$ and your angle is then just $\frac{\pi}{2} - CAB = BCA$.

Answer (score 0):

The angle between chord AC and tangent is half of ∠AOC.

To see this, let's expand on Derek Jennings answer @DerekJennings ,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eFkR.png

[Derek Jennings diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eFkR.png)

Let point M denote the midpoint of chord AC. Note that a line OM is perpendicular to AC. Therefore OM is parallel to alternate chord BC.

Considering the diameter AB as a traversal of parallel lines OM and BC, identical angles are created at both intersections.

Since by definition OM bisects ∠AOC.

Comment: unable to get image to display